# Controller Redirect issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a controller with name users_controller, within the login action I want to redirect to my affiliate_redirect_controller.php, now I the following code in the users controller to redirect

```
$this->redirect(array(
      'controller'=>'affiliate_redirect',
      'action'=>'logRedirect' ));
```

And then I get the following error which I can't seem to resolve

```
Error: The requested address '/affiliate_redirect/logRedirect' was not found on this server.
```

I honestly do not know what this could be, quite new to cakePHP and none of the solutions found work for me.

the contents of affiliate_redirect_controller.php looks like this

```
class AffiliateRedirectController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'AffiliateRedirect';

    function logRedirect(){
     }
}
```

Comment: try giving direct path $this->redirect('/affiliate_redirect/logRedirect');
According to cake's conventions the controller name should be AffiliateRedirects, filename affiliate_redirects_controller; this shouldn't be a problem here but check it anyways.

Comment: @Ehtesham, no it's not working, could it perhaps be my naming conventions?

Comment: well, just for testing rename controller filename to affiliates.php,class name to AffiliatesController, $name = 'Affiliates' and then see if it works $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'affilates', 'action' => 'logRedirect'));

Comment: Something else needs to be wrong, getting the same problem without the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is a mistake in your code its because of naming convention.

```
$this->redirect(array(
      'controller'=>'affiliate_redirects',
      'action'=>'logRedirect' ));
```

Please see the above changes when you are writing your controller name in lowercase like above it should be plural `affiliate_redirects` and should not be `affiliate_redirect`

Apart from this you can use directly redirect as like this also.

```
$this->redirect('affiliate_redirects/logRedirect');
```

Please try, it should work.

Comment: It's redirectingto the logRedirect method, how I know is when I echo something in the method it echoes, but the error is still there, could this be because of no view?

Comment: Yes you're right. There should be always a view associated with every action. If you do not wish to have any view then just write a statement $this->autoRender = false; OR if you do not want any main layout for it then just use $this->layout = 'ajax';

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a table in your database that corresponds to affiliate redirect controller?

You might want to rethink your logic, and use CakePHP routes to set the URL to what you want. Having a controller named affiliate_redirect_controller doesn't follow CakePHP's naming conventions.

Since I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, I don't know if this will work for you, but maybe consider redirecting to a separate action in UsersController like `/users/affiliate_redirect/`
Or you can create an `AffiliatesController` and then redirect to `/affiliates/redirect/`

Also, if you don't have debug mode set to 2, you should do that. It may help reveal what the actual issue is.

Comment: No I need to add a table, but did not do it yet. So the correct naming convention of the controller file would be affiliateredirect_controller.php if the class is named AffiliateRedirect. The AffiliateController basically logs a entry in the database and then redirects the user to where he needs to be

Comment: The Correct file name would be `affiliate_redirects_controller.php` the class name would be `AffiliateRedirectsController` and the $name would be `AffiliateRedirects` , then you would create a database table named `affiliate_redirects` and a model named `affiliate_redirect.php`

Answer (score 0):

What debug level do you have in app/config/core.php ? Most of the time, when you get the message

```
Error: The requested address '/controller/action' was not found on this server.
```

it means you have a debug level set to 0 and increasing it to 1 or 2 allows to get more details about the error.

Comment: It's at Zero I will set it to 1, when I set it to 2 I get a couple of deprecated errors. but the deprecated thing should not be the problem because all other controllers work